# Data warehouse design, multiple dimensions or one dimension with attributes?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, dimensions, dimensional-modeling

Working on a data warehouse and am looking for suggestions on having numerous dimensions versus on large dimension with attributes.

We currently have DimEntity, DimStation, DimZone, DimGroup, DimCompany and have multiple fact tables that contain the keys from each of the dimensions.  Is this the best way or would it be better to have just one dimension, DimEntity and include station, zone, group and company as attributes of the entity?

We have already gone the route of separate dimensions with our ETL so it isn't like the work to populate and build out the star schema is an issue.  Performance and maintainability are important.  These dimensions do not change often so looking for guidance on the best way to handle such dimensions.

Fact tables have over 100 million records.  The entity dimension has around 1000 records and the others listed have under 200 each.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no real way to answer this question without knowing a lot of details about what your entities are, what their attributes are, what your fact tables represent, how users want to view the data, what capabilities your reporting tools have etc. Perhaps if you can make your question more specific you may get a better response.

Comment: I'd like people who vote down to give a reason. Also for those who say add more information, how about giving the person time to update before you just go down voting.  Some people actually have lives and are not glued to their computer 24/7.  Get a life.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but FWIW anonymous downvoting has been discussed [many times](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=anonymous+downvoting) on the meta site and the conclusion - so far - has always been to allow it. You can read those threads to see the various arguments on both sides.

Comment: Hi Pondlife, sorry if it sounded like I was talking about you.  It was not pointed towards you.  I just didn't know where to put my comment about the down vote:)

Comment: No problem, I didn't assume it was me but I thought it might be useful to point you at some information about downvoting and why you can't expect comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your star schema table definitions, data cardinality, etc, it's tough to give a yes or no. It's going to be a balancing act.

For read performance, the fact table should be as skinny as possible and the dimension should be as short (low row count) as possible. Consolidating dimensions typically means that the fact table gets skinnier while the dimension record count increases.

If you can consolidate dimensions without adding a significant number of rows to the consolidated dimension, it may be worth looking into. It may be that you can combine the low cardinality dimensions into a junk dimension and achieve a nice balance. Dimensions with high cardinality attributes shouldn't be consolidated.

[Here's](http://www.widama.us/Documents/Kimball-DimensionalModeling.PDF) a good Kimball University article on dimensional modeling. Look specifically where he addresses centipede fact tables and how he recommends using junk dimensions.